# function over list mathematica

Tags: list-manipulation, data

I work on problem that need to define function with two list of data as follow

```
a = {0.1, 0.233, 0.65, 1.56};
b = {0.99, 0.8, 0.9, 1.9};

ELCDM1[z_?NumericQ, om_?NumericQ] := 1/Sqrt[om*(1 + z)^3 + 1 - om];

angdist[zmin_?NumberQ, zmax_?NumberQ, om_?NumberQ] := (3*10^5)/(

   1 + zmax) NIntegrate[ELCDM1[z, om], {z, zmin, zmax}];
```

"a" is list of lower bound of integrate and b is upper bound. The true outcome for my function "angdis" is
{100707., 71762., 25625.6, 13508.}. For me I should put first list "a" to my function and at the end of my program put list "b" so as I did as follow  the outcome is different with {100707., 71762., 25625.6, 13508.}.

```
angdist3[x_, om_] := (3*10^5)/(1 + #) NIntegrate[ELCDM1[z, om], {z, x, #}] & /@b;

angdist3[#, 0.3] & /@ a
```

here is the outcome :

```
{{100707., 92199.9, 97142.2, 111441.}, {82220.6, 71762., 77779.9, 
  98755.}, {32424.9, 16710.2, 25625.6, 
  64584.9}, {-42008.8, -65580.4, -52333.9, 13508.}}
```

I want to define function such as angdist3[x_, om_] at the end and give me : {100707., 71762., 25625.6, 13508.} but give me a wrong list .

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Perhaps you are looking for `MapThread[angdist[#1, #2, 0.3]&, {a, b}]`

Comment: Thanks for replying.It's true when I put both list to first function but as I mentioned I should define in two- 
                                                                                                                              steps..first put 'b' that I define  angdist3  and the last step put 'a'.

Comment: In "angdist3[#, om] & /@ a" om has no value. angdist3 then feeds om to ELCDM1 that can therefore not be evaluated, neither can the integral. Is this what you want?

Comment: thanks ..it should be 0.3

Comment: How about `Diagonal[angdist3[#, 0.3] & /@ a]`

Comment: it's work.That's what I was looking for.Thanks very much @SimonWoods

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you need to compute all 16 (4×4) integrals and then extract the diagonal elements, use [`Diagonal`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Diagonal.html):

```
Diagonal[angdist3[#, 0.3] & /@ a]

{100707., 71762., 25625.6, 13508.}
```

You could instead compute only those 4 results. [`MapThread`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/MapThread.html) will map over both `a` and `b` simultaneously:

```
MapThread[angdist[#1, #2, 0.3] &, {a, b}]

{100707., 71762., 25625.6, 13508.}
```

Alternatively you can give `angdist` the [`Listable`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Listable.html) attribute, and simply pass `a` and `b` as arguments:

```
SetAttributes[angdist, Listable]
angdist[a, b, 0.3]

{100707., 71762., 25625.6, 13508.}
```